# Applying opacity to an image

Tags: html, css

I want to apply opacity to an image. The problem is that the opacity is also applying to the H1 text within the image. How can I apply the opacity to only the image?

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron quem-somos">
    <h1>Quem somos?</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.quem-somos {
  background-image: url('../images/capa8.png');
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

The result of the above code is:

[image]

Comment: Opacity is applied to the div and its children. Define a separate element for the image and use opacity for it

Comment: But then you get al sorts of annoying sizing issues for the image-element, whereas a background-image never goes beyond the content of the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Drixson Oseña's answer accomplishes exactly what you want.

But if for some reason you need the image to truly be a CSS background image (e.g., you need it to repeat or something like that), then something like the following approach should work. Similar to what Drixson was doing, it uses absolute positioning to stack two elements on top of one another, with separate opacity set for each one.

```css
div.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 911px;
  height: 223px;
}
div.background {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/DQM3xDw.png');
  width: 911px;
  height: 223px;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
div.quem-somos {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="jumbotron quem-somos">
    <h1>Quem somos?</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to be honest, this is not a very flexible answer, with absolute width and height values for the divs

Comment: Thus the phrase *something like the following approach*. It's custom fit for the image in question, but of course should be modified if a different image is needed, or the full image doesn't need to be displayed, or the background image needs to repeat for a larger container, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Opacity is applied to your container. You should put your image not in background.
Try something like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="position:relative;width:300px;">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DQM3xDw.png" style="opacity:0.4;position:absolute;width:100%;" />
<h1>Quem somos?</h1>
```

Update:
Image width now will rely to it's container width.

Comment: I believe your answer creates an unwanted size for the background image, because now it's not truly a `background-image` anymore

Comment: @myfunkyside I understand, I've adjusted my answer the image is responsive on it's parent div. Unfortunately im not good in height